# How to store prescriptions in SQL Server 2008 R2 database (clinic project)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm thinking of designing a form as prescription, feed it with the data, then capture it and print, and save captured image in the database as image.

But I'm afraid of database growth when I save every prescription as an image in the database (after years), I'm afraid it will reach a size limit (I need to store all prescription content in one column in `patient` table).

Is that right to save the prescriptions this way? Or are there better ways to save the prescription to retrieve and print it at any time?

Can I save the prescription content as seperated strings in one cell (separated by any sign like ($$)), when user try to retrieve a prescription the program seperate the cell content (make every $$ a new line) and draw them to the form to print?

Comment: I would *definitely* recommend to store the **actual data** - not the screenshot of the prescription. And I would also recommend **not to re-invent the wheel** yet again - don't invent a new "scheme" of storing multiple pieces of data into a string - use existing standards - either **XML**, or **JSON** or something like that!

Comment: I saw some Rx data is inserted in 1 column with 1 special character like you metioned $$. Imagine that an image has much unnecessary data like white blank spaces and so on. Saving in 1 column is good option and you're needed to design your algorithm whats to be in order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save prescription header data in a table, prescription rows in another table and create an algorithm which can provide a printed format.
You will save place and will be able to query your data. Or archive it after 5,10,etc years. 
This kind of data is relative small is it is only strings, no binary data.